# Can't get rid of “Your connection to website is encrypted with obsolete cryptography”

Tags: cryptography, certificates, chrome

In my Nginx config I have:

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;     
ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout 10m;
```

But on Chrome cert icon, I still get the "Your connection to website is encrypted with obsolete cryptography" message. Any suggestions on what to do to get rid of this message?

Comment: There are lots of questions on this here. Have a search and see if another's question has your answer.

Comment: Change your crypto?

Comment: I did.... I've pasted all the recommended `ssl_ciphers` directive, bounced nginx, and still no success.

Comment: Try the config from the [Mozilla SSL config generator.](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/ "Mozilla SSL config generator")

Comment: Details! What clients? Screenshot!  What SSL Labs test result? (Screenshot) What domain name?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a sha1 intermediate certificate in the chain from your cert to the root certs on that device? I think this message has nothing to do with the cipher suite.

Answer (score 3):

These ciphers are old:

```
DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:SRP-DSS-AES-256-CBC-SHA:SRP-RSA-AES-256-CBC-SHA:SRP-AES-256-CBC-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA256:SRP-DSS-AES-128-CBC-SHA:SRP-RSA-AES-128-CBC-SHA:SRP-AES-128-CBC-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA256-SHA:CAMELLIA256-SHA:DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA:DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA128-SHA
```

The fastest way to get rid of them is to append to ciphersuite this:

```
!EDH-DSS:!SRP
```

Also, do not forget to define your own DH parameters or all connections with DHE- ciphers are weak!

If you want to have very good security, you can use this cipher suite, as it is:

```
EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM:EECDH+ECDSA+AES256:EECDH+ECDSA+AES:EECDH+AESGCM:EECDH+AES256:EECDH+AES:EDH+AESGCM:EDH+AES256:EDH+AES:EECDH+ECDSA+3DES:EECDH+3DES:EDH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES256:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!NULL:!RC4:!EDH+DSS:!MD5
```

Comment: "do not forget to define your own DH parameters or all DHE- ciphers are weak" - No, the ciphers are not weak. The use of shared ECDH groups is potentially problematic, and steps should be taken to generate your own parameters, but that doesn't make the cipher weak.

Comment: OK, fixed to be more accurate.

Comment: @Polynomial: s/shared ECDH groups/shared DH groups/ ? Or s/shared ECDH groups/named ECDH curves/ ?

Comment: @StackzOfZtuff Sorry, I conflated the two.